# Importing a variable into HTML

Tags: javascript

So I am currently trying to take a variable from my Main.js and import into a file called Iframe.html, the subject is a string containing the subject of a ticket from zen-desk I have the api working and it is grabbing the ticket subject however when I then try to implement that into the recognition system for the "BC-", it doesn't recognise.

This is the Main.js file with the variable "Subject" defined

```
function showInfo(data) {
  var requester_data = {
    //'email': data.ticket.address
    //'name': data.ticket.name
    'description': data.ticket.description,
    'subject': data.ticket.subject
  };
  var source = $("#requester-template").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html = template(requester_data);
  $("#content").html(html);
}
```

And this is the Iframe.html file that I am trying to import the variable "Subject" across to:

```
<!--BC-Check six digit-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function bc_check() {
    var str = {{subject}};
    var res = str.substring(str.indexOf("BC-"), str.indexOf("BC-") + 9);
    document.getElementById("recognize").innerHTML = res;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to extract the variable requester_data out of the function but give it values inside it like you're doing it already.

I think your problem is that the variable requester_data belongs to the function and doesnt to the scope.